# Automate print jobs to file

Tags: printing

I am trying to automate printing to a file on windows. For each file, I would like somehow to have the print job mapped to a unique file. I was only able to go as far as all print jobs print to the same file overwriting the old one. Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a filename that has a high probability of being unique: a concatenation of date and time elements:

{descriptivefilename}-{ms}-{s}-{m}-{h}-{year}-{day}-{month}.{ext}

If you're using a batch file, add this line after printing:

```
for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=:" %%d in ("%time%") do COPY "C:\myprintfile.prn" %%d-%%e-%%f.prn
```

This will copy the print file to a filename that should be unique since it includes the fractional seconds.  On subsequent passes, the previous print job will be overwritten and copied to its own filename, which represents the time it was done printing.

Comment: ..of course this depends on the number of concurrent users, machines, etc.  You can add more elements into the formula for creating your filename: machine name, username, etc

Comment: I am using the FILE: port in windows, but it pops up the dialog for a file name each time a new job prints. What I am trying to do is somehow to generate a unique name and avoid the dialog popup since this is done for automation.